# Handling of Firestore IDs in models and entities

Tags: flutter, domain-driven-design

I'm learning `domain driven design` for Flutter apps. I understand that the model is used between the infrastructure layer and the use-case, and the entity is used between in the use case and the UI.

Let's say that my app is dealing with books and I'm storing my books in `Cloud Firestore`. I have defined a very simple `BookEntity` with an id and a title.

```
@freezed
class BookEntity with _$BookEntity {
  const factory BookEntity({
    required String firestoreId, // This is the ID of the document in firestore
    required String title,
  }) = _BookEntity;
}
```

I believe that the ID of the document should be in the entity, because if I need to modify this book in the Firestore I will need to know the reference of the document, right?

As you know, in firestore the id is not part of the data themselves. When I read my database, I would be using the code below.

```
// code not tested
FirebaseFirestore
    .instance
    .collection('books')
    .doc('uXSin0z3gqPHwhVLCP98')
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
  snapshot.id;      // -> 'uXSin0z3gqPHwhVLCP98'
  snapshot.data();  // -> {title: 'To Kill a Mockingbird', price: 11.69, year: 1960}
});
```

Somewhere, I will need to put the id together with the data. I think the right place to do it is in the model, which is created in the repository. I think my model would probably look very similar to the Entity:

```
@freezed
class BookModel with _$BookModel {
  const factory BookModel({
    required String firestoreId,
    required String title,
  }) = _BookModel;
}
```

And, when fetching data from Firestore I would create a model with:

```
BookModel(
  firestoreId: snapshot.id,
  title: snapshot.data()?['title'],
);
```

This can then be converted to a BookEntity which will be consumed by the UI.

The problem is that when I am reversing the flow, when I am creating a new book, the ID of the firestore document is not known in the presentation and domain layers. Therefore my `BookEntity` and `BookModel` must be updated so that the id is optional. The entity and the model now look like this

```
@freezed
class BookEntity with _$BookEntity {
  const factory BookEntity({
    String? firestoreId,
    required String title,
  }) = _BookEntity;
}

@freezed
class BookModel with _$BookModel {
  const factory BookModel({
    String? firestoreId,
    required String title,
  }) = _BookModel;
}
```

The problem is that now, every time I need to access the `firestoreId` field of my `BookEntity`, whose data originate from Firestore, I need to test whether the `firestoreId` field is null or not. But it cannot be null because the data come from Firestore, so there is always an ID. So I will either write a lot of null-checks, or use the `!` (which I don't like).

In short, the "upstream" and "downstream" flows have different requirements for the `firestoreId` field. The *Firebase -> UI* flow needs a `String`, and the *UI -> Firebase* flow needs a `String?`.

So the question is what is the **best and cleanest** way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firestoreId` should be nullable, because it make sense for `BookEntity` to have `firestoreId` sometime and not have `firestoreId` sometime.

You probably don't need to use `firestoreId` in the UI, and It's only needed when writing to the Firestore. So you can have a `writeToFirestore` method and only use a single null check there.

You can also generate a new random id locally whenever a new `BookEntity` is created. Using your own document id when creating a document in Firestore

One more solution is to use `late final String firestoreId`, but it's skipping null check making debuging harder and doesn't work with `Freezed`.